# why alpha unchanged? I want backgroundView was visible while load Network Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

1. List item

> ```
> UIView *backgroundViewLoad = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
> [self.view addSubview:backgroundLoad];
>
> UIActivityIndicate *activity = [[UIActivityIndicate alloc] init];
> activity.center = backgroundViewLoad.center;
> [backgroundViewLoad addSubview:activity];
>
> [backgroundViewLoad setAlpha:1];
>
> //load Network Data
>
> [UIView setAlpha:0];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added subview backgroundViewLoad, just change this:

```
[self.view addSubview:backgroundLoad];
```

to this:

```
[self.view addSubview: backgroundViewLoad];
```